# How to connect a layout view with an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

In my main view, I have:

```
public class PlayersActivity extends Activity {
    ViewFlipper flipper;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playercontainer);
        flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    }
}
```

with this view:

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include android:id="@+id/first"  layout="@layout/first" />
    <include android:id="@+id/second"  layout="@layout/playerdetailsview" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

It displays the first view correctly but I want it to be connected to a java class so I created an FirstActivity class where I can control all my components in the first view
but how do I attach the first.xml layout with the FirstActivity java class ?

Comment: PlayersActivity already is your java class for controlling your components.  How would class FirstActivity differ from PlayersActivity?

Comment: to splits up my functionality in different classes so i can reuse that specific layout in othere viewflippers

Answer (score 53):

Say your new xml file is `foo.xml`:

1. Put `foo.xml` file in your `res/layout` directory.
2. In your new class use `setContentView(R.layout.foo);`
3. Specify your new class in your [manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

See also the topic on [declaring layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

Comment: Step 3 assumes your class is an activity.

Comment: i did add <activity android:name="FirstActivity"></activity>  in the application node (and followed the other steps to) but it still doesn't call the class do i define it right in the manifest ?

Comment: You need to specify the fully qualified name.  Assuming the class resides in the same package as your manifest, you can shorten by specifying as

<activity android:name=".FirstActivity"></activity>

(note the leading ".")

Comment: @RickNotFred: I'd done all this as mentioned. but still there's problem at line `setContentView(R.layout.FirstActivity);` `FirstActivity` is not resolved or is not a field.

Answer (score 6):

1) Create an xml file (say `foo.xml`).
2) Put `foo.xml` in `res/layout` directory.
3) Edit `foo.xml` and put some android layout code and save it. e.g.,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1" 
                 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

4) In your new activity class put

```
setContentView(R.layout.foo);
```

For creating an activity [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690851/android-creating-a-new-activity-in-eclipse/3693641#3693641)

I guess the problem with your xml file is that you had not specified any layout for the activity.

Answer (score 3):

Not so hard to link 2 layouts just do :

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View args0) {
    setContentView(R.layout.aardelayout);
}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to do it this way

Answer (score 0):

Change the name from `FirstActivity` to `firstactivity`.
Layout does not accept caps.