# Navigation through pages

Tags: android, navigation, android-layout

I'm very very new on Android development.

I have designed two xmls layouts (main.xml and secondpage.xml). I want to go from main.xml to secondpage.xml when the user click on a button.

I've found on android's documentation the following methods:

- [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)
- [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

and more and more methods...

Should may use these methods to navigate throug pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, create a second activity and your secondpage.xml should be its layout. And then switch to the new activity and layout using `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`. See my answer to a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690851/android-creating-a-new-activity-in-eclipse/3693641) for how to create and call a new activity in Eclipse.

Being a newbie myself I like to help others, and I hope this helps you.