# Android App starting activity_main.xml

Tags: android, eclipse

I made an android app but I wanted to start a new activity (.xml).
Normally when an app starts it shows direct the activity_main.xml layout file.
I don't know how that is going on so what's the code for this because so I know how to start a new activity.

Comment: then you have to improve your search. There are a lot of tutorials available.

Comment: @ BenjaminStrike normalley u can write code for intent

Comment: I understand it is about creating a new screen?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690851/android-creating-a-new-activity-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple u have need in main activity :-

```
 {
(R.layout.main_activity);
   Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AnotherActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
 }  
and then you have create `AnotherActivity.class
and insert another layout for AnotherActivity in (R.layout.anotherlayout);
that solve
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the layout you want to show in your Activity using setContentView method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layoutForYourActivity);
```

This has to be specified inside your onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Create a new activity through *New -> Other -> Android -> Android Activity*

A activity is a *.java* file, the *.xml* is only the layout.
Call the new activity with

```
intent = new Intent(main.this, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I suggest you to do some basic tutorials.