# Starting New Activity is not working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-debug

I wrote an application in which a new activity should start,and the activity did not start when i ran the application on my device.

I tried to debug that using debugger, the debugger gave me a result telling me that "Source is not found" in a new tab labeled "ActivityThread.performeLaunchActivity()

Am new on here so i couldn't post a picture of it, this link refer to a picture showing the same result i had https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kIMb.jpg

Comment: Post your startActivity code (with the Intent). Also, make sure there's no crash on the started Activity's onCreate.

Comment: What is your logcat? Have you mentioned your activity in manifest?

Comment: Try this option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690851/android-creating-a-new-activity-in-eclipse

Comment: This is my startActivity code https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Y4VyCEm5De0/VB6U3t7tsfI/AAAAAAAAAx4/5wLeQwWya40/s219-p/Capture.JPG

And this is the debugging result https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-k6QctzbNHTw/VB6U3lI1OII/AAAAAAAAAx0/xJk_yFZBQgw/s800/Capture1.JPG

And this is the manifest https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Vlvh58vL0MY/VB6VgXbvisI/AAAAAAAAAyM/w3T2TsZV8Xg/s145-p/Capture3.JPG

Comment: post your real code, not a screenshot.